# Fetch last 25 CoreData entries by date

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a Core Data Entity:

```
@objc(Messages)
class Messages: NSManagedObject {

     @NSManaged var receiver: String?
     @NSManaged var time: NSDate?
     @NSManaged var message: String?
}
```

In which I save the time with `var time = NSDate()`

I try to fetch the data like this:

```
func fetchData(limit: Int, sort: Bool, sorter: String) -> Array<AnyObject> {
    let freq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: self.coreDataEntity)
    freq.fetchLimit = limit
    if sort == true {
        freq.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: sorter, ascending: false)]
    }
    do {
        try self.fetchArray = context.executeFetchRequest(freq)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("CoreData - Fehler (fetch): \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    fetchArray.reverse()
    return fetchArray!
}
```

What I want is the last 25 entries. The latest entry should be the last one in the array.

I call it with:

```
var messages:Array<AnyObject> = []
...
self.messages = fetchData(25, sort: true, sorter: "time")
```

But `fetchArray.reverse()` is doing nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse *returns* an array composed of the elements in reverse order, it does not re-arrange the items in the existing array.  Just amend to:

```
let newArray = fetchArray.reverse()
fetchArray = newArray
return fetchArray!
```

Comment: For the second line I get `Cannot assign a value of type 'ReverseRandomAccessCollection<[AnyObject]>' to a value of type 'Array<AnyObject>?'`

Comment: It works with `let newArray = fetchArray.reverse() as Array` - thank you

Comment: @PhilHarmonie Sorry, the code in my answer compiles fine in Swift 1.2, but  gives that error in Swift 2.  Glad you were able to find the correct cast (`as Array`).